# Python: Comparison between list items that isn't redundant

Tags: python, for-loop, optimization, comparison, graph-algorithm

Say I have a list nested within a key of a dict. So something like this:

```
d = {'people':['John', 'Carry', 'Joe', 'Greg', 'Carl', 'Gene']}
```

And I want to compare the people in the list with each other so that I can make a graph connecting names that start with the same first letter.

I came up with a nested for loop to try and solve this:

```
for subject in d.keys():
        for word1 in d[people]:
            for word2 in d[people]:
                if word1[0] == word2[0]:
                    g.connectThem(word1,word2)
```

But the nested for loop can get redundant since it will make the same comparisons twice over. Is there any way to make it so there will be no redundancy in regards to comparison?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through pairs using `itertools.combinations`

```
for pair in itertools.combinations(d['people'], 2):
    first, second = pair
    if first[0] == second[0]:
        g.connectThem(first, second)
```

These are the pairs that are produced from `combinations`

```
[('John', 'Carry'), ('John', 'Joe'), ('John', 'Greg'), ('John', 'Carl'), ('John', 'Gene'),
 ('Carry', 'Joe'), ('Carry', 'Greg'), ('Carry', 'Carl'), ('Carry', 'Gene'),
 ('Joe', 'Greg'), ('Joe', 'Carl'), ('Joe', 'Gene'),
 ('Greg', 'Carl'), ('Greg', 'Gene'),
 ('Carl', 'Gene')]
```

Notice you do not have the issue of repeats (by reversing the order of the pair).
Assuming your `connectThem` function works, this should produce your desired behavior.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out combinations. They are surely what I was looking for in this example!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *to compare the people in the list with each other so that I can make a graph connecting names that start with the same first letter.* then use a dict and a single pass over `d["people"]` where you use the first letters of names as the keys so the solution is `0(n)` and markedly more efficient than the quadratic getting all combinations which creates mostly unnecessary pairings:

```
d = {"people":['John', 'Carry', 'Joe', 'Greg', 'Carl', 'Gene']}

from collections import defaultdict

my_d = defaultdict(list)

for v in d["people"]:
    my_d[v[0]].append(v)
print(my_d)
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'C': ['Carry', 'Carl'], 'J': ['John', 'Joe'], 'G': ['Greg', 'Gene']})
```

You can now pass complete lists of names with common first names to a method to add to the graph by just iterating over the values of `my_d`.

If you want to create combinations of people in lists lengths that are > 2 then you can it will save making multiple unnecessary combinations using the original list. It will only combine the actual names you want.

So to handle duplicate names, only make combinations from names with a common first letter and only consider groups that have links i.e names with non unique first letters:

```
from collections import defaultdict
# store all names in groups, grouped by common first letter in names
my_d = defaultdict(set)

for v in d["people"]:
     # 0(1) set lookup avoids adding names twice
    if v not in my_d[v[0]]:
        my_d[v[0]].add(v)


from itertools import combinations

for group in my_d.itervalues():
    # two elements are a combination
    if len(group) == 2:
        g.connectThem(group[0],group[1])   
    # ignore uniques names ?     
    elif len(group) > 2:
        for n1,n2  in combinations(group,2):            
            g.connectThem(n1 ,n2)
```

Without using itertools at all we can see that because our linear pass creates a dict of groupings we can simply loop over each value list in out dict and create uniques pairings:

```
for group in my_d.itervalues():
    for ind, n1 in enumerate(group):
        for n2 in group[ind+1:]:
            print(n1,n2)
('Carry', 'Carl')
('John', 'Joe')
('Greg', 'Gene')
```

Comment: You have taught me something very useful. I appreciate it. I will definitely use defaultdict in the future. Although this isn't exactly what I was looking for you really nailed it with an optimized way to tackle the specific example I was working with. Thanks so much!

Comment: This will actually do exactly the same thing just a massive amount more efficiently by first doing a linear pass to group  and then getting combinations. For a large list the just using combinations will scale very very badly

Comment: You are right. Once again, thank you for showing me defaultdict.